# Angular 2: Wrapping a component inside a parent component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to put a component inside a parent component, like how it could be done in React.

React example:

**Parent Component**:

```
<div>
  Hello from parent
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```

**Child component**:

```
<ParentComponent>
  Hello from child
</ParentComponent>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to include child in between the parent tag.

Passing an @Input of elements comes to mind, but it sounded so wrong and ugly.

Comment: You need to use component's selector in your html. I suggest to go through official tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#show-the-heroescomponent-view

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial. Including a component inside another component, yes. But I'm looking to include the parent component in a child, and placing the children content to the specified placeholder in the parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Parent Component:**

```
<div>
  Hello from parent
  <ng-content select=".txt"></ng-content>
</div>
```

**Child component:**

```
<ParentComponent>
  <ng-container class="txt">
        Hello from child
    </ng-container>
</ParentComponent>
```

**Output:**
Hello from parent
Hello from child

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Given that your child component has a selector, say it's called `app-child`, then inside the parent component's HTML template you call it like this:

```
<div>
  Hello from parent
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

Now, all you have inside your child component's HTML will be displayed as is. Also, should you need to pass input from the parent to the child, you could do something like this:

```
<div>
  Hello from parent
  <app-child [objInChild]="valFromParent"></app-child>
</div>
```

where `valFromParent` is a value that the parent can provide, and `objInChild` is the object you annotate with `@Input` in your child's class component (say in the file `child.component.ts`) to receive the passed in value.